# Using Elastic Search Geo Functionality To Find Most Common Locations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, geolocation, location, geojson

I have a geojson file containing a list of locations each with a longitude, latitude and timestamp. Note the longitudes and latitudes are multiplied by 10000000.

```
{
  "locations" : [ {
    "timestampMs" : "1461820561530",
    "latitudeE7" : -378107308,
    "longitudeE7" : 1449654070,
    "accuracy" : 35,
    "junk_i_want_to_save_but_ignore" : [ { .. } ]
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1461820455813",
    "latitudeE7" : -378107279,
    "longitudeE7" : 1449673809,
    "accuracy" : 33
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1461820281089",
    "latitudeE7" : -378105184,
    "longitudeE7" : 1449254023,
    "accuracy" : 35
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1461820155814",
    "latitudeE7" : -378177434,
    "longitudeE7" : 1429653949,
    "accuracy" : 34
  }
  ..
```

Many of these locations will be the same physical location (e.g. the user's home) but obviously the longitude and latitudes may not be exactly the same.

I would like to use  Elastic Search and it's Geo functionality to produce a ranked list of most common locations where locations are deemed to be the same if they are within, say, 100m of each other?

For each common location I'd also like the list of all timestamps they were at that location if possible!

I'd very much appreciate a sample query to get me started!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show a sample document and your mapping? Make it easier for people to bootstrap your issue and try to solve it.

Comment: Hi Val. Good point! I've included the example data above.

Comment: If this GeoJSON data is properly indexed, then you can use the `geohash_grid` aggregation in order to see how each location is distributed in the two-dimensional space (in ~100m rectangles). You can also combine that with a `date_histogram` aggregation and see how the points are distributed in time.

Comment: Excellent Val that sounds perfect. I'm totally new to Elastic Search and Geo stuff so will see if I can come up with a query and let you know if it works.

Comment: First and foremost, make sure to properly index your data. Something like this should get you started: `{"location":{"lat":40,"lon":70}, "timestamp": 1458432895726, "accuracy": 15}`, where `location` is a `geo_point`, and `timestamp` and `accuracy` are `long`

Comment: Hi Val. Many thanks for getting me started. I tried: ```PUT /locations/
{
    "mappings": { 
       "location": {
          "properties": {
             "location": {                
                "type": "geo_point",
                "fields": {
                    "latitudeE7": {"type": "long"},
                    "longitudeE7": {"type" : "long"}
                }
             },
             "timestampMs": {
                "type": "long"
             },
             "accuracy": {
                "type": "long"
             }
          }
       }
    }
}```

Comment: (Split across multiple comments as too long!) then: ```POST /locations/location/
{
    "timestampMs" : "1461820561530",
    "latitudeE7" : -378107308,
    "longitudeE7" : 1449654070,
    "accuracy" : 35
}``` then: ```GET /locations/location/_search?``` but I don't see the location nested object of typegeo_point you defined above.

Comment: You should simply UPDATE your question, it's far more legible than in comments.

Comment: Can you explain in what unit are your latitude/longitude fields?

Comment: Updated the description thanks Val.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work you need to modify your mapping like this:

```
PUT /locations
{
  "mappings": {
    "location": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "timestampMs": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "accuracy": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when you index your documents, you need to divide the latitude and longitude by 10000000, and index like this:

```
PUT /locations/location/1
{
  "timestampMs": "1461820561530",
  "location": {
    "lat": -37.8103308,
    "lon": 14.4967407
  },
  "accuracy": 35
}
```

Finally, your search query below...

```
POST /locations/location/_search
{
  "aggregations": {
    "zoomedInView": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
          "location": {
            "top_left": "-37, 14",
            "bottom_right": "-38, 15"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "zoom1": {
          "geohash_grid": {
            "field": "location",
            "precision": 6
          },
          "aggs": {
            "ts": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestampMs",
                "interval": "15m",
                "format": "DDD yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...will yield the following result:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "zoomedInView": {
      "doc_count": 1,
      "zoom1": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "k362cu",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "ts": {
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key_as_string": "Thu 2016-04-28 05:15",
                  "key": 1461820500000,
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to our discussion, here is a solution that could work for you. Using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html), you can call your API and retrieve the big JSON document (using the [`http_poller` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html)), extract/transform all locations and sink them to Elasticsearch (with the [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html)) very easily.

Here is how it goes in order to format each event as depicted in my initial answer.

1. Using `http_poller` you can retrieve the JSON locations (note that I've set the polling interval to 1 day, but you can change that to some other value, or simply run Logstash manually each time you want to retrieve the locations)
2. Then we `split` the locations array into individual events
3. Then we divide the latitude/longitude fields by 10,000,000 to get proper coordinates
4. We also need to clean it up a bit by moving and removing some fields
5. Finally, we just send each event to Elasticsearch

Logstash configuration `locations.conf`:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      get_locations => {
        method => get
        url => "http://your_api.com/locations.json"
        headers => {
          Accept => "application/json"
        }
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    interval => 86400000
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
  split {
    field => "locations" 
  }
  ruby {
    code => "
      event['location'] = {
        'lat' => event['locations']['latitudeE7'] / 10000000.0,
        'lon' => event['locations']['longitudeE7'] / 10000000.0
      }
    "
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "timestampMs" => "%{[locations][timestampMs]}"
      "accuracy" => "%{[locations][accuracy]}"
      "junk_i_want_to_save_but_ignore" => "%{[locations][junk_i_want_to_save_but_ignore]}"
    }
    remove_field => [
      "locations", "@timestamp", "@version" 
    ]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "locations"
    document_type => "location"
  }
}
```

You can then run with the following command:

```
bin/logstash -f locations.conf
```

When that has run, you can launch your search query and you should get what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Val that's great! Is it non trivial to get a list of all timestamMs in each of the buckets?

Comment: Do you want each timestamp or you want to group them by minute, hour, day and simply get how many there are by groups?

Comment: Hi Val, good idea about grouping. If it is possible to group them by day of the week, hour and 15 minute intervals that'd be amazing! e.g. Monday 06 15-29: 3 meant there were 3 events on any Monday between 6:15am and 6:29am but I assume that's quite hard?

Comment: Also is it possible to ingest the data with a script to convert my E7 numbers to conventional long and lats as I have no control over the source data. Cheers!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a `date_histogram` sub-aggregation that does exactly what you need, i.e. bucket all timestamps by period of 15 minutes

Comment: For ingesting, I'd advise to use Logstash which will allow you to transform your input to exactly the above format.

Comment: Hi Val, wow the date_histogram is perfect! I don't know much about logstash but the input JSON is not coming from logs but from another API endpoint which we want to ingest straight into Elastic Search (talking of which is it possible to ingest the whole array of locations at once?)

Comment: Can the client calling the other API endpoint do that small transformation before sending the docs to ES?

Comment: Hi Val - we can use the latest ES if that helps. It'd be best if we could just chuck the whole array of locations (including the `"junk_i_want_to_save_but_ignore" : [ { .. } ]`) at ES to ingest if poss.

Comment: Hi Val. Thanks for making me think about this - the document JSON I have to hand is actually a massive 130MB big with events from 2014 in it! I only want events from the last month indexed though.

Comment: I think it'd be nice if your client app which queries the API endpoint could be able to chew that big file somehow. It has to anyway, since you only want to send the last month of data... unless the API provides support for only querying the last month of data. Is that the case?

Comment: Hi Val - no the API is fixed. Ideally I'd like to throw the whole file at Elastic Search and have it convert the long and lats and ignore timestamps older than some threshold but if you say that's not possible I guess we'll have to write a process which mangles it first - what would you recommend we do that in? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the exact format of what you get through the API? i.e. do you get several documents or just one big document with a huge `locations` array?

Comment: One big document with a huge huge locations array as in my question.

Comment: Ok, and does the JSON response come back pretty-printed / formatted or on a unformatted single line?

Comment: Formatted and indented multiple lines :)

Comment: Will this need to be run often or just once every now and then?

Comment: Yes just run now and then for each user - probably once a week(ish). We'll need to ignore all but the last month of data in the massive formatted multiline JSON response that comes for each user.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a potential solution that should work for you.

Comment: Hi Val! Great! I'm sure you already realised from the crazy size of the file, the JSON format isn't actually the format we get back from the API... (it's the supplier's export format!). Sorry. I have amended the question with the actual format which is a single line XML file. Is there anything in the actual format I need to look out for when modifying your excellent answer to import the events? Many thanks!

Comment: Arghhh, changing requirements :-)

Comment: Sorry. I can hopefully work out how to do it from your excellent answer above. Assuming that works for a single line?

Comment: My answer works for single/multiline JSON data, but not (yet) for XML data.

Comment: Since the initial requirement changed completely, I suggest that you create another question with the new XML requirement and we let this thread be as the answer works for your initial question. The key point is to not cram too much into a single question and keep the thread as clean as possible to help people find solutions to similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Val. I've removed the XML from this question and made a new question: 37008930

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a look.

Comment: Thanks Val much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Val. Should I take the same approach as above for question 37008930 just modifying the ingest to cope with the single line or is there a better way to achieve it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi Val. Hope you had a good weekend. Just wondering if you had any time upcoming for question 37008930 as unfortunately I'm still struggling and nobody else has answered yet. Sorry to be a pain! Cheers!

Comment: I'll give it a shot shortly.

Comment: Thanks Val much appreciated.

Comment: I included ```"aggs": {
            "ts": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestampMs",
                "interval": "15m",
                "format": "DDD yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
              }
             },
             "map_zoom": { 
                "geo_bounds": {
                    "field":     "location"
                }
            }
          }``` to get the coords of the smallest box around the hash coords.