# Using Elastic Search Geo Functionality To Find Most Common Locations from XML raw data

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, geolocation, logstash

I would like to use Elastic Search and it's Geo functionality to produce a ranked ordered list of most common locations where locations are deemed to be the same if they are within, say, 100m of each other on a day of the week basis.

Many of these locations will be the same physical location (e.g. the user's home) but obviously the longitude and latitudes may not be exactly the same.

The data considered for each day of the week, should be same day of the week over the entire data period (which will be one month). For example, searching for common locations on a date which happens to be a Tuesday we should query data from last Tuesday, the Tuesday before, the Tuesday before that and the Tuesday before before that(!) [Perhaps this can be achieved by using ES indexes?].

For each search day I'd also like a histogram to 15 min accuracy of all the times they were within 100m of that location again including the last 4 weeks of data on the same day of the week.

We can make an API raw data request for a single day only (so will need multiple requests to get the last four weeks of data). The third party API out of our control will return XML in the following format - all on a single line and unformatted (I manually formatted the example below). The coord is (longitude, latitude) format. The last digit (0 in the example below) represents altitude and should be stored if possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
   <Document>
      [stuff we don't care about]
      <Day>
         [stuff we don't care about]
         <Locations>
        [stuff we don't care about]
            <time>2016-04-30T19:35:01.558+10:00</time>
            <coord>142.9987247 -37.328203799999996 0</coord>
            <time>2016-05-02T12:29:21.233+10:00</time>
            <coord>142.96122699999998 -37.921569999999996 0</coord>
            ....
         </Locations>
      </Day>
   </Document>
</kml>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What does the third number inside the `coord` element represent? Altitude or accuracy? If the former, where is the accuracy field you had in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880258/using-elastic-search-geo-functionality-to-find-most-common-locations)?

Comment: Hi Val. Thanks for getting to this. Good questions. The last digit (0 in the example) represents altitude and should be stored if possible. There is no accuracy field in this version! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880258/using-elastic-search-geo-functionality-to-find-most-common-locations), it is possible to parse the given XML and index the resulting locations into elasticsearch pretty easily. There's some XML parsing to do and then some data massage to perform in order to extract the data, but it is possible.

I've come up with the pretty straightforward Logstash configuration below:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      get_locations => {
        method => get
        url => "http://your-api.com/locations.xml"
        headers => {
          Accept => "application/xml"
        }
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    interval => 60
    codec => "plain"
  }
}
filter {
  # 1. parse XML
  xml {
    source => "message"
    force_array => false
    target => "parsed"
  }

  # 2. parse time/coord arrays and rebuild pairs
  ruby {
    code => "
      event['locations'] = []
      event['parsed']['Document']['Day']['Locations']['time'].each { |time|
        event['locations'].push({'time' => time, 'location' => nil})
      }
      event['parsed']['Document']['Day']['Locations']['coord'].each_with_index { |coord, i|
        event['locations'][i]['location'] = {
          'lon' => coord.split(' ')[0],
          'lat' => coord.split(' ')[1]
        }
      }
    "
  }

  # 3. produce one event per time/coord pair
  split {
    field => "locations"
  }

  # 4. Some renaming and clean-ups    
  mutate {
    rename => {
      "[locations][time]" => "timestampMs"
      "[locations][location]" => "location"
    }
    remove_field => [
      "parsed", "message", "@timestamp", "@version", "locations"
    ]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "locations"
    document_type => "location"
  }
}
```

First, I'm using an `http_poller` input in order to pull the XML data

Then, I'm using an `xml` filter in order to parse the XML into JSON. The XML you provided would result in the following JSON:

```
 {
    "Document" => {
        "Day" => {
            "Locations" => {
                 "time" => [
                    [0] "2016-04-30T19:35:01.558+10:00",
                    [1] "2016-05-02T12:29:21.233+10:00"
                ],
                "coord" => [
                    [0] "142.9987247 -37.328203799999996 0",
                    [1] "142.96122699999998 -37.921569999999996 0"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, due to the clumsy XML organization, the `time` and `coord` values are all glued together inside their respective arrays.

I'm then leveraging the `ruby` filter in order to split it all out and re-unite each `time` with its appropriate `coord` value. I basically iterate over each array and re-construct the proper `time/coord` pairs and store them into a new `locations` array. Note that the altitude part is [not yet supported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10510) in the current version of Elasticsearch.

Then I `split` that new `locations` array in order to produce one event per `time/coord` pair.

Finally I'm doing some clean-ups and the events that will be indexed into Elasticsearch look as follows:

```
{
 "timestampMs" => "2016-04-30T19:35:01.558+10:00",
    "location" => {
         "lon" => "142.9987247",
         "lat" => "-37.328203799999996"
    }
}
{
 "timestampMs" => "2016-05-02T12:29:21.233+10:00",
    "location" => {
         "lon" => "142.96122699999998",
         "lat" => "-37.921569999999996"
    }
}
```

You can then run `bin/logstash -f locations.conf` in order to run your pipeline.

With that in place you can then reuse the same aggregation as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880258/using-elastic-search-geo-functionality-to-find-most-common-locations) and that will work.

Comment: Any tips on how to make the query take a search date and from that calculate the day of the week and then filter only data from the same day of the week in the dataset to satisfy: "For example, searching for common locations on a date which happens to be a Tuesday we should query data from last Tuesday, the Tuesday before, the Tuesday before that and the Tuesday before before that"

Comment: Now that we have dialed in the ingestion phase, let's handle this next requirement in another question, so we don't cram too many things into the same thread.

Comment: Hi Val. Good point. I resolved it via some Googling: ```event['locations'].push({'time' => time, 'location' => nil, 'dayOfWeek' => Date.parse(time).strftime('%a')})```

Comment: Hi Val. Many thanks - I'm getting the hang of ES thanks to your help! Still can't get my head around the other parts of the question so as you suggested I made a new question 37381322 if you happen to get a chance to check it out/I need to make it clearer. Thanks again!